# error: bool operator== must take exactly two arguments

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have an operator== class member in the FileDir class in this header file:

```
#include <sstream>   

class FileDir {

public:   

    FileDir(std::string nameVal, long sizeVal = 4, bool typeVal = false);   

    FileDir(const FileDir &obj);   

    ~FileDir();            // destructor   

    long getSize() const;    

    std::string getName() const;   

    bool isFile() const;   

    std::string rename(std::string newname);     

    long resize(long newsize);    

    std::string toString();    

    bool operator== (const FileDir &dir1);        

private:

    std::string name;

    long size;

    bool type;

};
```

And this is the implementation:

```
bool operator== (const FileDir &dir1) {

    if (this->name == dir1.name && this->size == dir1.size && this->type == dir1.type)

        return true;

    else

        return false;

}
```

This is the error I get from the compiler:

```
FileDir.cpp:101:37: error: ‘bool operator==(const FileDir&)’ must take exactly two arguments
 bool operator== (const FileDir &dir1) {
                                     ^
make: *** [fdTest] Error 1
```

I think that since the operator is a class member, it should have only one explicit parameter. So why the error?

Comment: `bool FileDir::operator==(...)`. Since you are defining it out of class, you need to tell the compiler it's a class member.

Comment: You should probably make `operator==` `const` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like any member function, you need a `Class::` prefix on the name of the function when you define it outside the body.  But in this case the name of the function is `operator==`.  You need:

```
bool FileDir::operator== (const FileDir &dir1) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
bool FileDir::operator== (const FileDir &dir1) const{
    if (this->name == dir1.name && 
        this->size == dir1.size && 
        this->type == dir1.type)
    return true;
else
    return false;        
}
```

OR

Carry your implementation in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
friend bool operator==(const FileDir & dir) const;
```

in the 'xxx.h'file to define your function.
You overloaded the '==' sign, so you must to define it to a friend function